# Common web service for asp.net, iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, asp.net, android, web-services

What are the necessary points that we should keep in mind while developing web service .NET that can be accessed by ASP.NET and mobile phones like iPhone and Android?

Comment: for android and web (do no bout iphone)... json is easier to use than xml try to made web service which speak jsonish :)

Answer (score 2):

Web services by design are platform agnostic, which means that you should be able to access them from any application. However depending upon the relevant framework options available different implementations might be easier to access that others (XML/SOAP via .NET as an example).

Building a REST service serving up JSON could be your best option for an easy adoption on multiple platforms.

[REST vs SOAP](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm)

Comment: How did you handle the amount of data returned to web and mobile? Does it make any difference?

Comment: The amount of data returned is in your hands. You're building the service, that's your call.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services

1.It Can be accessed only over HTTP
2.It works in stateless environment

WCF

WCF is flexible because its services can be hosted in different types of applications. The following lists several common scenarios for hosting WCF services:
IIS
WAS
Self-hosting
Managed Windows Service

For mobile application check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sry_143/4010/

For ASP.Net application check http://geekswithblogs.net/nestor/articles/108042.aspx

Happy coding!!